# Add columns to multiple tables in schema

Tags: sql, db2, alter

I need to alter multiple tables in a schema, for all tables prefixed with something, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA"."TABLE1"
ADD ( "COLUMN1"   CHARACTER(4)  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'DATA',
    "COLUMN2"   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'MORE_DATA',
);
```

I need this to iterate over multiple tables, like SCHEMA.table1,  SCHEMA.table2... and so on. There is around 800 tables in the schema.

I was wondering if there is some kind of wildcard that I could use? I was looking at creating a cursor from the System tables, but was sure there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

What I tend to do in those cases, if the DBMS doesn't provide an easy way to do it, is to simply write a script that will do it for me. Something like:

```
db2 "select tbname from sysibm.systables where schema = 'SCHEMA'" >tblist
# Edit tblist here to remove headers and such.
for t in $(cat tblist) ; do
    db2 "alter table SCHEMA.${t} add ..."
done
```

That's `bash` type format, you'll need to adapt for whatever scripting tool you use.

Comment: +1: Basically, this requires some form of dynamic SQL.  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` (sp?) is ANSI standard, supported on SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL to simplify these things.  Personally, I prefer hardcoded statements in DDL scripts - easier to find things when you need to review in case there's an undocumented table.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's input,

After creating what was (I thought) fancy procedure using a CURSOR and while loop to iterate through the tables, I decided since it is a once off to build an ALTER query for each of the tables from a select statement thus:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'ALTER TABLE '
          || 'CTP0610'
          || '.'
          || name
          || ' ADD COLUMN SOURCE_SYSTEM_CODE CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''CCR'' '
          || ' ADD COLUMN RECORD_TYPE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''INSERT'' '
          || ' ADD COLUMN COMMIT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '
          || ' ADD COLUMN EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT; '
    FROM sysibm.systables
    WHERE (NAME LIKE 'CCTL_%')
    OR (NAME LIKE 'CCX_%')
    OR (NAME LIKE 'CC_%');
```

I pasted the resultant queries into a query window and ran it, it turned out to be around 1500 tables. I guess sometimes the least elegant solution is good enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use the undocumented `sp_MSforeachTable`. You'll find lots of help on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=sp_MSforeachTable) for that.</strike>

OP did not specify DB2 originally. My answer is thus redundant.

Comment: It helps if you include a summary explanation here, with a link to more information if the asker needs it. When SO has taken over the world and is the first Google result for "sp_MSforeachTable", the person who clicks the link is going to be very annoyed with this answer

Comment: Is this available in DB2? I forgot to mention that this is the Database type.

Comment: OP did not specify that it was DB2, which makes my answer redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The following will add a column to all tables with a specific schema (e.g., MySchema) within a specific database (e.g., MyDatabase)

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(max)
declare @sqlstring nvarchar(max)
declare cur cursor for 
select 
    [TABLE_SCHEMA] + '.' + [TABLE_NAME] from MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
where 
    [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'MySchema'

open cur
    fetch next from cur into @tablename
    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
        set @sqlstring = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tablename + ' ADD MyColumn DateTime NOT NULL'

        exec sp_executesql @sqlstring

        fetch next from cur into @tablename
    end

close cur
deallocate cur
```